# What is the .cs file under MyDataContext.dbml for?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq-to-sql, datacontext

What is that individual (currently empty) file under MyDataContext.dbml for?

Directory structure:

```
Mydatacontext.dbml
    MyDataContext.cs
    MyDataContext.dbml.layout
    MyDataContext.designer.cs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's normally used for you to add a partial `MyDataContext` class with custom code that won't be overwritten during code generation. If you edited MyDataContext.designer.cs instead, your hand-written code would be erased.

Comment: Perfect I was actually looking for a place to put that code. Thanks!

Comment: Please be aware you can't use `using` outside of `namespace` - `.designed.cs` generator will crash unexpectedly.